# When I change an attributeReference textString property the position of my BlockReference changes?

Tags: c#, .net, autocad

I have copied a blockReference that was in my first file dwg to an existing file with the method WblockCloneObjects method. I have set the position of this blockReference and it worked fine.

The problem is when I change the attributeReference textString property, My blockReference change the position and the value of the attribute isn't visible in the blockReference.

Here it is my code:

```
private bool SetIssueNumber(Transaction toTransaction, BlockReference deepClonedIssue, string identifier)
{
    //Get the attributeCollection
    Autodesk.AutoCAD.DatabaseServices.AttributeCollection attrCollection = deepClonedIssue.AttributeCollection;
    //Get the object
    foreach (ObjectId idAttrReference in attrCollection)
    {
        AttributeReference attributeReference =
            toTransaction.GetObject(idAttrReference, OpenMode.ForWrite) as AttributeReference;
        if (attributeReference == null)
            return false;
        if (attributeReference.Tag.Equals("ISSUENUMBER"))
        {
            attributeReference.TextString = identifier;
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

When I remove:

```
attributeReference.TextString = identifier;
```

The blockReference shows up in the expecting position but When it's executed, I observe that the position change and the value of attribute doesn't show up.

Comment: `AttributeReference` implements `IDisposable`. So it should be inside a `using` block. Other then that it look okay. Do you commit your transaction?

Comment: Yes,  I commit my transaction, the attribute textString has changed.

Comment: @Nitram, you only need to dispose AutoCAD entities if you don't add them to the database.

Comment: I have added the blockReference to the database. but when I try to change the value of the attribute, the position change of the blockReference. I am trying to understand why ?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how you're deepcloning the block reference, but you may also need to transform (move/rotate/scale) the attribute. Here is the method with notes from the help file.

> AttributeReference.SetAttributeFromBlock Method (Matrix3d)
>
> Applies blockTransform to the attribute's geometric data to transform
>   the position, sizing, and obliquing as would be done by the INSERT
>   command. The attribute's textual and entity properties data is left
>   alone.

Comment: For the deepcloning method, This is the method: